# Laravel could not establish connection whit host on any mail_encryption (tls, ssl, starttls)

Tags: email, connection, host, laravel-5.7

Im having this error

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp-mail.outlook.com [Unable to find the socket transport "starttls"
>   - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

this is .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=some@mail.net
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=starttls
```

end openssl in php is enabled.

I tried all encryptions, different ports, but its the same error. What could be the issue here? I searched the web and this website but no solution for me.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, Did you fix ?

Comment: I jumped back to gmail and it works now, but it was a long time ago. forgot really what was the issue.

Comment: yup! it works with other SMTP but not the one from office365 which has encryption STARTTLS. anyway, thank you :)

Comment: no problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue already and forgot to update the fix. I found the problem that password contains some empty string in suffix. So that it was not established the connection. I removed the empty spaces and system sends email.

Answer (score 0):

In the laravel 7 `.env` file, add

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<mailid>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=STARTTLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=<mailid>
```